# How to move/copy a message to another user's mailbox using MailKit and imap?

Tags: email, imap, mail-server, mailkit

I'm creating an automation system which has a catchall mailbox and receives every non-existing email delivered to the mail server.

I then do some tasks based on some of these emails. But sometimes the message must be delivered to one of the existing mailboxes.

My question is, how can I, using the domain's admin account and IMAP protocol, move/copy these messages to the existing mailboxes using the MailKit library?

I think I have figured out this much that the IMAP's MOVE command which maps to `ImapClient.Inbox.Move` in MailKit, is supposedly meant for this purpose, but what I can't figure out is, how to access the "Complete Hierarchy" namespace on IMAP to find the right user's Inbox folder?

Comment: Generally, an IMAP server only exposes a single users namespace.  Specific alternate namespaces are server specific and you will need to look up the documentation for it to find out what they are.  The `NAMESPACE` extension may tell you some alternate hierarchies that you can inspect if your server supports it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most IMAP servers sandbox themselves such that your account can't see another user's account.

I suspect there's no way for even your admin account to see other user's accounts. That would be a massive privacy issue.

This is, at best, going to be specific to the exact IMAP server software you are using, but I would not expect to be able to do what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @jstedfast. I'm using dovecot for the IMAP server and it comes with a tool called doveadm which has the functionality that I was looking for. I solved it that way.